# Why part of https requests fail on Charles Proxy as some https requests are ok?

Tags: charles-proxy

I set everything well and some https request did be proxied well, but some are still `unknown` , is there any new way I don't known to prevent being proxied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the https connections checked the cert on apps their own. Which means you can't just add the cert to your device's system and hope it works.

There are more works should be done to capture these data by using proxy.

More detailed things are you have to hack the app to capture. For those information just google "JustTrustMe".